# File Sharing Issue

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing

So I am having some trouble with file sharing(Windows 10 20H2). While in file explorer, few folders have an icon at the left bottom saying `State:Shared`. This is not my OS, someone installed a custom ISO on my computer and I was wondering if it's connected to some other computer?

I've never tried file sharing so I have no idea how it works. I disabled the 'Server' service that would disable file sharing but I never checked if there is any connection to another computer, is there any way to do that?

[image: Image of file explorer]

Comment: So do you want to disable file sharing? Or block the shared folders? Can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: I want to disable file sharing,and also remove any connections to other computers.

Comment: I think OP just wants to gain some ease-of-mind, likely either by some definitive method to verify the presence of unauthorized file access, or apply the configuration(s) necessary to prevent such access.

Comment: Yeah that's kind of what I meant to say,I never interacted with file sharing or network sharing in windows before,I've used pretty much every feature besides this one and I don't know if somebody may be having access to my files or not.

Answer (score 0):

To remove sharing from an individual folder:

- Right-click on the folder.
- Select *Properties*.
- On the *Sharing* tab of the *Properties* dialog, click on *Advanced Sharing*.
- In the *Advanced Sharin* dialog, click to remove the check mark in *Share this folder*.

That folder is no longer shared. Though you can *globally* turn off all sharing, this might interfere with remote administration, printing, etc.

[image: Remove sharing from a folder]

To list all shared folders:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type "comput".
- Select the *Computer Management* control panel applet.
- Expand the *Shares* item.

[image: List shared folders in Computer Management]